# What is the current list of existing Ensembles? Are there Statistical Ensembles which haven't been observed yet?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I've taken a course in graduate statistical mechanics, and it seems like the concept of statistical ensemble is flexible. We talked about Micro and grand canonical, as well as one or two more. I'm curious about what kinds of existing and hypothetical ensembles exist within the physics community.

Comment: There is isolated (micro canonical), closed (canonical) and open (grand canonical). Almost all calculations are based on these. What others would you expect?